# How to solve "Rather than invoking init scripts...." on Ubuntu 14

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04

I'm using a docker container of Ubuntu 14.

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release # this is in the container
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS"
```

When I typed `service cron start` in the container, I have the following error. I think the following error doesn't make sence for me because the error should be showed when I use `/etc/init.d/cron start`.

```
$ service cron start
Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service cron start

Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the start(8) utility, e.g. start cron
```

When I typed `/etc/init.d/cron start` in the container. The same error is showed as `service cron start`

Could you tell me how to solve the error and how to start `cron` in the docker container?

Answer (score 2):

To run cron daemon you can simply invoke 'cron':

```
root@89bdd8666c95:# cron   
root@89bdd8666c95:# ps -ef
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 14:56 ?        00:00:00 bash
root        88     1  0 15:02 ?        00:00:00 cron
root        89     1  0 15:02 ?        00:00:00 ps -ef
```